# Unable to to connect remotely to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, networking, firewall, robo3t

Currently I am having trouble remote connecting a mongodb server on my virtual Ubuntu machine. I am unable to connect to with with Robomongo client that is running on my Windows PC that is also running the vm.

Here are the IP Addressees for both pcs

Windows:

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.137
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
```

Ubuntu:

```
enp0s3 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:6c:fc:9c
      inet addr:192.168.1.134  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::9785:55d7:130:6618/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:5021 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:465 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:1231057 (1.2 MB)  TX bytes:45237 (45.2 KB)
```

The error that I am getting on windows that show it can't connect:
[image]

Netstat that shows mongo is running:

```
netstat -tulpn | grep 27017
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3611/mongod
```

From this point I tried to connect locally to the server and it works:

```
mongo --port 27017
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.10
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27017/test
```

Then I tried to add port 27017 to the ufw and still unable to connect:

```
sudo ufw status
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
27017                      ALLOW       Anywhere                  
27017 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Well, `127.0.0.1` cannot be the source address for any traffic outside the host. You are trying to source the server from the loopback address, not an address that can be used outside the server host.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. It was due to the bind_ip flag in my mongodb.conf being set to 127.0.0.1. This is why I as only able to connect locally to the mongodb server.

**Resolution was to comment out the bind_ip flag so it would not white list the IP Addresses.**

Mongodb.conf

```
# mongodb.conf



# Where to store the data.

dbpath=/home/<username>/mongodb



#where to log

logpath=/home/<username>/mongodb/logs/mongodb.log



logappend=true



#bind_ip = 127.0.0.1

port = 27017



# Enable journaling, http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Journaling

journal=true



# Enables periodic logging of CPU utilization and I/O wait

#cpu = true



# Turn on/off security.  Off is currently the default

#noauth = true

#auth = true



# Verbose logging output.

#verbose = true



# Inspect all client data for validity on receipt (useful for

# developing drivers)

#objcheck = true



# Enable db quota management

#quota = true



# Set oplogging level where n is

#   0=off (default)

#   1=W

#   2=R

#   3=both

#   7=W+some reads

#oplog = 0



# Diagnostic/debugging option

#nocursors = true



# Ignore query hints

#nohints = true



# Disable the HTTP interface (Defaults to localhost:27018).

#nohttpinterface = true



# Turns off server-side scripting.  This will result in greatly limited

# functionality

#noscripting = true



# Turns off table scans.  Any query that would do a table scan fails.

#notablescan = true



# Disable data file preallocation.

#noprealloc = true



# Specify .ns file size for new databases.

# nssize = <size>



# Accout token for Mongo monitoring server.

#mms-token = <token>



# Server name for Mongo monitoring server.

#mms-name = <server-name>



# Ping interval for Mongo monitoring server.

#mms-interval = <seconds>



# Replication Options



# in replicated mongo databases, specify here whether this is a slave or master

#slave = true

#source = master.example.com

# Slave only: specify a single database to replicate

#only = master.example.com

# or

#master = true

#source = slave.example.com



# Address of a server to pair with.

#pairwith = <server:port>

# Address of arbiter server.

#arbiter = <server:port>

# Automatically resync if slave data is stale

#autoresync

# Custom size for replication operation log.

#oplogSize = <MB>

# Size limit for in-memory storage of op ids.

#opIdMem = <bytes>



# SSL options

# Enable SSL on normal ports

#sslOnNormalPorts = true

# SSL Key file and password

#sslPEMKeyFile = /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem

#sslPEMKeyPassword = pass
```